# Date Only cannot be mapped SQL Server 2019

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am trying to use the new DateOnly aspects of c# but when I come to do my migrations I am having the following issue. I am using SQL Server 2019 the error is.

> 'Amenitie.StartDate could not be mapped because it is of type 'DateOnly', which is not a supported primitive type or a valid entity type. Either explicitly map this property, or ignore it using the'

My model is as follows

```
public class Amenitie
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public Rooms? Rooms { get; set; }
    public string? Description { get; set; }
    public DateOnly StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateOnly EndDate { get; set; }
    public bool? isAvailable { get; set; }
    public bool? isDeleted { get; set; }
    public bool? isActive { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreateDate { get; set; }
}
```

My Dal project and my web project are both set to

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
  <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I am using the following package versions.

```
<ItemGroup>
 <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity" Version="2.2.0" />
 <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.9" />
 <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.9" />
 <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="5.0.9">
 <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
 <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
 </PackageReference>
 <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.Design" Version="2.0.0-preview1-final" />
 <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="5.0.9" />
 <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design" Version="2.0.0-preview1-final" />
 <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="5.0.9">
  <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
  <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
 </PackageReference>
 <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="5.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Is `DateOnly` available in EF Core 6 and above I presume?

Comment: Well, considering the DateOnly type is new for .NET 6, that seems like a reasonable presumption. Have you tried applying the ColumnAttribute and specifying that those fields are date fields?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have two choices:

1. use *DateTime* instead of *DateOnly*.
2. build a custom converter (see below).

As far I can see, the actual version of Entity Framework Core issue tracker states that model builder does not support it ([find the issue here](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/24507)). Building a converter may solve your issue (cited from there):

```
protected override void ConfigureConventions(ModelConfigurationBuilder builder)
{
   builder.Properties<DateOnly>()
          .HaveConversion<DateOnlyConverter, DateOnlyComparer>()
          .HaveColumnType("date");
}
```

Comment: Then why do they have it their seems pointless.

Comment: .NET 6 and EF Core are two different projects with two different teams.

Comment: Support must be added to the underlying ADO.NET provider first (Microsoft.Data.SqlClient)

Comment: "Then why do they have it their seems pointless."
You need to have the type itself available before adding support for various database providers. Func fact: The above solution does currently not work in RC2 for Nullable DateOnly. See the linked issue for more details.

Comment: @boj mysql and postgresql map dateonly just fine

Comment: @cikatomo hm, nice...

Comment: UPDATE: It appears that support has been added in EF Core 8, which is planned to release in Nov 2023. https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/29989

Answer (score 42):

Try this

```cs
public class YourDbContext : DbContext
{
    Ctors() {...}

    protected override void ConfigureConventions(ModelConfigurationBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Properties<DateOnly>()
                .HaveConversion<DateOnlyConverter>()
                .HaveColumnType("date");
    }
}
              
/// <summary>
/// Converts <see cref="DateOnly" /> to <see cref="DateTime"/> and vice versa.
/// </summary>
public class DateOnlyConverter : ValueConverter<DateOnly, DateTime>
{
   /// <summary>
   /// Creates a new instance of this converter.
   /// </summary>
   public DateOnlyConverter() : base(
       d => d.ToDateTime(TimeOnly.MinValue),
       d => DateOnly.FromDateTime(d))
  { }
}
```

EDIT: with RC2 this does not work for *nullable* types.

EDIT 2: with NET6 release version this works for *nullable* types again, and more than that, you dont need to have a separate converter for "DateOnly?" anymore.

EDIT 3: with NET 8 built-in support has been added and the only thing you need to do is:

```cs
public class YourDbContext : DbContext
{
    Ctors() {...}

    protected override void ConfigureConventions(ModelConfigurationBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Properties<DateOnly>()
           .HaveColumnType("date");
    }
}
```

Comment: It feels as if this really ought to have been built in.

Comment: Anyone interested should check out https://erikej.github.io/dotnet/sqlclient/2022/11/17/sqlclient-dateonly.html

Comment: I believe that should be HaveColumnType("date") rather than HasColumnType("date").

Comment: See yourself: https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/fluent-api/hascolumntype-method

Comment: No it's `HaveColumnType`. 

You use the `HasColumnType` method when configuring a single property, such as in your linked example. When configuring multiple properties, such as all DateOnly properties, you use `HaveColumnType`.

If you don't believe me try pasting your ConfigureConventions into your code. You'll get a compiler error telling you the extension method is defined on `ComplexTypePrimitiveCollectionBuilder` not on `PropertiesConfigurationBuilder<DateOnly>`.

Comment: Basically they wanted to make sure the method name is always grammatically correct.

Answer (score 0):

The feature you are looking for in EF Core with net6.0 is probably unavailable because your project is the version `5.x.x` Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.* packages.

However, DateOnly and TimeOnly were not scaffolded converted to `Date` and `Time` SQL types in NET6 but this is a new feature in NET8.

For anybody landing here, try upgrading your project to NET8 and installing the correct version of EF Core `8.x.x`.  i.e.:

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="8.0.0">
  <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
  <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="8.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="8.0.0">
  <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
  <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
</PackageReference>
```