# The property could not be mapped because it is of type 'DateOnly', which is not a supported primitive type or a valid entity type

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, ef-code-first, .net-6.0

The property 'Ogrenci.OgrenciBirthDate' could not be mapped because it is of type 'DateOnly', which is not a supported primitive type or a valid entity type. Either explicitly map this property, or ignore it using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

```
    //modelclass


    [DisplayName("Doğum Tarihi")]
    public DateOnly OgrenciBirthDate { get; set; }


    //controller
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult Create(Ogretmen obj)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //obj.OgretmenBirthDate = DateTime.Now;
            _db.Ogretmenler.Add(obj);
            _db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(obj);
    }
```

i am getting this error and i am trying to take birth date of user and collect it in sql, i just want date, not time, so first i tried to do it with DateTime but it gave another error and also it gives the time value which i dont want. What should i do

Comment: As the error says, mapping to date is not yet supported

Comment: `DateOnly` is very new. We've been using `DateTime` for only dates for two decades now, so it is absolutely possible. You just did it wrong. EF doesn't support `DateOnly` yet so you cannot use it at the entity level. You'll need to use `DateTime` and ask a different question about the other issue. You can use `DateOnly` in your DTOs and view models.

Comment: When you use `DateTime`, you simply ignore the time part. You can use the `Date` property to get another `DateTime` with the same date and the time zeroed and when formatting to a `string` for display, you simply use a format that doesn't include the time, e.g. "d".

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/69146423/120955

Answer (score 14):

Here is a converter for `DateOnly`, where the column type in the database is `date`

```
public class DateOnlyConverter : ValueConverter<DateOnly, DateTime>
{
    public DateOnlyConverter() 
        : base(dateOnly => 
                dateOnly.ToDateTime(TimeOnly.MinValue), 
            dateTime => DateOnly.FromDateTime(dateTime)) { }
}
```

Add the following method to your `DbContext` class which handles conversions for all properties in your models of type `DateOnly`

```
protected override void ConfigureConventions(ModelConfigurationBuilder builder)
{

    builder.Properties<DateOnly>()
        .HaveConversion<DateOnlyConverter>()
        .HaveColumnType("date");

    base.ConfigureConventions(builder);

}
```

Setup a property in your model

```
public DateOnly? OgrenciBirthDate { get; set; }
```

See also [Pre-convention configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/bulk-configuration#pre-convention-configuration)

**Udate 02/2023** There is an NuGet package for this now [ErikEJ.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.DateOnlyTimeOnly](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ErikEJ.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.DateOnlyTimeOnly)

**Update 7/27/2023**

See EF Core 8 preview for [DateOnly/TimeOnly supported on SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-8.0/whatsnew#dateonlytimeonly-supported-on-sql-server)

**Update 11/2023**

EF Core 8 natively supports DateOnly and TimeOnly

[SQL Server date and time now scaffold to .NET DateOnly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-8.0/breaking-changes#sql-server-date-and-time-now-scaffold-to-net-dateonly-and-timeonly)

Comment: I had the same error above and I tried adding the nuget package, but unfortunately it did not fix the problem..

Comment: Perhaps try this [code sample](https://github.com/karenpayneoregon/dateonly-primer/tree/master/EntityFrameworkCoreDateOnly) from the following [article](https://dev.to/karenpayneoregon/learn-dateonly-timeonly-23j0). Otherwise post a new question and reference back to this question as an option.